# Error creating Facebook test user

Tags: facebook

I am following the instructions at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

When I do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
  installed=true
  &name=Fred
  &locale=en_US
  &permissions=read_stream
  &method=post
  &access_token=XXXXXXXXX
```

I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: APP_ID",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Without wanting to ask too stupid a question, you definitely are using the app access token (for the same app), and are using an actual app ID instead of the string 'APP_ID'? Are you sure the app ID is correct?

Comment: I am using a fresh access token returned by: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXX&grant_type=client_credentials. I got the client ID and secret from Facebook. Since I got an access token, I assume the client_id and client_secret were good.

Comment: *sigh* i confused this with another question and just added (and deleted) an incorrect answer - please disregard if you've seen it. Last thing I can think of (which, if this is the case is an incorrect error message) - is your app's 'App Type' set to 'native / Desktop'? If so, the app access token won't be trusted to make API calls on the app's behalf

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using the string APP_ID instead of your app's id.

---

*Further Explanation*

I was able to duplicate the bug myself with the following steps:

1. Getting a App Access Token:

   `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`

   where YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_APP_SECRET were replaced with the correct values from https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Using the provided access token, appending it to the url.

   `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?installed=true&name=Fred&locale=en_US&permissions=read_stream&method=post&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

   which result in

   ```
   {
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: APP_ID",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
      }
   }
   ```
3. Replacing APP_ID with the proper app id, also from https://developers.facebook.com/apps resulted in the correct response.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method and it works:

https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_APPID/accounts/test-users?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN&installed=true&locale=en_GB&permissions=read_stream,read_friendlists,publish_stream

the APP_ACCESS_TOKEN :
Creating an APP_ACCESS_TOKEN is really easy. You can use your App ID/API Key and App secret

```
YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN = YOUR_APP_ID|YOUR_APP_SECRET
```

Example: `1234587968 | bghyuifjk3438483249235903502035023504305`